# How to switch AsyncTask to Loader simplest way?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How do you switch from AsyncTask to Loader? do I need to create a new java class for loader?

My current code :

```
}
private class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.loading, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String stream = null;
        String urlString = strings[0];

        GoogleAPI hh = new GoogleAPI();
        stream = hh.GetGoogleAPI(urlString);
        return stream;
    }
```

But wanna change AsyncTask to Loader. How? Tq.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {
public ProcessJSON (Context context) {
    super(context);
}
@Override 
public String loadInBackground() {
    return "ProcessJSON";
  }
}
```

Implements LoaderManager Callback in your activity.

YourActivity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String>{

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
 getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this).forceLoad();
 }

@Override 
public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
  return new ProcessJSON(YourActivity.this);
}
@Override 
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, List<Employee> data) {
 //do something on finished
}
@Override 
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> loader) {
//do something
}


}
```